# How to filter documents in ElasticSearch by counting number in array?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which contains keyword array like:

```
tags : ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']
```

Is there a way to filter document, so i take only doc, where **'one'** appear **two times**, and ignore doc, where is only appear once?

```
GET /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "tags" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "grp1" :  {"bool" : {"must" : [
              {"term" : { "tags" : "one" } } // add condition appear twice in array
            ]
          }},
          "grp2" :  {"bool" : {"must" : [
              {"term" : { "tags" : "two" } },
              {"term" : { "tags" : "three" } }            
            ]
          }},
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the array regularly(not as keyword), you can use a match phrase query with high enough slop so that it matches values at any position in the array index.

```
    PUT test_index/_doc/1
    {
      "tags" : ["one", "two", "three", "one"]
    }
    
    PUT test_index/_doc/2
    {
      "tags" : ["one", "two", "three"]
    }

    GET test_index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "tags":{
            "query": "one one",
            "slop": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here I use a slop of 1000 because each item in the array index will start with a 100+ position. So we need a high enough slop to match a phrase with "one" at 0 position and another "one" at 303 position. Try running the below query and see the positions of each item

```
GET test_index/_analyze
    {
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "text": ["one", "two", "three", "one"]
    }
```